# Java Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath

Tags: java

I have an application that should work, but here I have a JAXB error. I don't know which version of Java it is, I think it's 8.

I run in Java 8. In Java 8+ iIhave to add javax.xml.bind and com.sun.xml.bind to pom. I also ran it with Java 11 and 16 and jakarta in the pom.

I have read that applications which are supposed to run on Java 8 but were running it on Java 11, generate this error, and that has jous in the pom of jakarta and javax.

And another question how to detect the Java to use? And that the solution applies according to the version of java

I have this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:131)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:318)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:478)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:435)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:336)
        at mypackage (ConsoleApp.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:92)
        at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:125)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:128)
        ... 5 more
```

Pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>myapp-parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>myapp-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>myapp-lst</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>example</name>
    <description></description>

    <properties>
        <plugin.download.version>1.4.1</plugin.download.version>
        <santuario.version>2.1.2</santuario.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.myapp-parent.myapp.mylist.app.ConsoleApp</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>download-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${plugin.download.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>CRL-IGC-ELEM-ORG</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wget</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <url>**url**</url>
                            <outputFileName>ACI-EL-ORG.crl</outputFileName>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/crls</outputDirectory>
                            <skipCache>true</skipCache>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>CRL-IGC-ELEM</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wget</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <url>**url**</url>
                            <outputFileName>ACR-EL.crl</outputFileName>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/crls</outputDirectory>
                            <skipCache>true</skipCache>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.dependency.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>download-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${plugin.download.version}</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ldaptive</groupId>
            <artifactId>ldaptive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ldaptive</groupId>
            <artifactId>ldaptive-unboundid</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
            <version>${santuario.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>chl-public-released</id>
            <name>releases</name>
            <url>**url**</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>chl-public-snapshots</id>
            <name>snapshots</name>
            <url>**url**</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: The `java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader` in the stacktrace indicates it is Java 9 or higher, which means you must explicitly add a JAXB-runtime on the classpath as it was removed from the Java distribution. The fact the exception is thrown from `javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance` means you do have the JAXB-API on the classpath. Adding the JAXB-runtime on the classpath works for Java 8, as well as higher version, even if Java 8 comes with JAXB.

Comment: This error potentially might also occur if you add a *too new* version of the JAXB-runtime on your classpath (a version that uses the `jakarta.xml.bind` package namespace instead of the `javax.xml.bind` package namespace).

Comment: if i use jdk16 for generate my project my idea suggests me  to add jakarta

Comment: Yes, but you need to take care *which version* you're using. Given you're using things from the package namespace `javax.xml.bind`, you need to use dependencies with version 2.3.x, not 3.x or higher (those versions switched to the package namespace `jakarta.xml.bind`). In any case, your pom.xml is missing a dependency on [org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.5](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.5/jar) (or another JAXB 2.3 implementation).

Comment: And to be clear, the library jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.3 uses the `javax.xml.bind` package namespace, while `jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:3.0.0` switched to package namespace `jakarta.xml.bind`.

Comment: thank you I already have version 2.3.x of jakarta these what my proposed my idea and indeed with missing glassfish.
i thought he was also included in jakarta

Comment: No, jakarta.xml.bind-api is only the API, and the GlassFish JAXB runtime is just one implementation of that API; there are others.

Answer (score 2):

it missed that in the pom

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
```